# Background gradient issue

Tags: css, background

I'm seeing a double background gradient on this page in Google Chrome.... any ideas why?

http://www.starcraft-source.com/member/login/

I need it to be the solid blue color

Comment: did you use any bacground repeat or so ??

Comment: I'm using Chrome 7.0.517.44 and don't see it. Perhaps you should post a screenshot

Comment: When I take the background-repeat off like KcSchaefer mentions it just turns white.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean the additional background gradient that appears below the footer?

```
html {
background:-moz-linear-gradient(center bottom , #1A405D 70%, #0A1C2D 92%) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
}
```

Needs to be

```
html {
background:-moz-linear-gradient(center bottom , #1A405D 70%, #0A1C2D 92%) no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
}
```

You shouldn't be repeating this kind of gradient background.

Of course, now you'll need to deal with whitespace below the footer, but that's a different issue.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I'd avoid styling the html element. You can use the gradient on the background-image, to free up background for a colour.
I'd use the following:

```
body{
background: #1A405D;
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#0A1C2D,#1A405D);
background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(center bottom , #1A405D 70%, #0A1C2D 92%);  
background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

This would give you a result as follows:
http://jsfiddle.net/Sapphion/QJwA6/

Answer (score 0):

You have put the gradient on the `html` element (which BTW is technically not wrong, but unusual), but the `html` doesn't fill the whole view port.

Try adding

```
html {
  height: 100%;
}
```